# OpenLDAP: Convert AD-Schema from *.ldif to *.schema

Tags: active-directory, openldap, ldif

I'm running an OpenLDAP 2.4.44 with the module back_ldap as LDAP Proxy for MS-AD-Servers (see for details: [openLDAP as proxy to Active Directory](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD)).

Now I need to add the schemata from AD-Server to the OpenLDAP-Server and I have exported the schemata from a MS-AD-Server with ldapsearch into a ldif-file (see for details: [How can I fetch schema information from the server?](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1366.html)).

Now I need to convert the ldif-format to a schema-format for OpenLDAP slapd.conf. It is not possible to load the ldif with ldapadd, because the OpenLDAP is running in proxy mode, so every request will be forwarded to MS-AD-Servers.

How do I convert the ldif-file to an schema file? Is there any tool. Or how to add a ldif-file to be loaded via slapd.conf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would need to do is to remove the attributes `dn`, `cn` and `objectClass` and replace all occurences of `olcAttributeTypes:` and `olcObjectClasses:` with `attributetype` and `objectclass` respectively.

You can also do it via shell.

One-liner on linux shell:

```
sed '/^dn: /d;/^objectClass: /d;/^cn: /d;s/olcAttributeTypes:/attributetype/g;s/olcObjectClasses:/objectclass/g' file.ldif > file.schema
```

Corresponding command in windows powershell:

```
Get-Content file.ldif | Where { $_ -notmatch "^dn: " } | Where { $_ -notmatch "^objectClass: " } | Where { $_ -notmatch "^cn: " } | %{ $_ -replace "olcObjectClasses:", "objectclass" } | %{ $_ -replace "olcAttributeTypes:", "attributetype" } | Out-File file.schema
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It doesn't actually convert from .ldif to .schema format.